# using pubmedR to search by doi

Tags: r, rentrez

trying to use the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150005/incomplete-affiliations-retrieved-with-pmapirequest-and-pmapi2df-from-pubmedr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103323/extracting-affiliation-information-from-pubmed-search-string-in-r) to extract author affiliation from a list of doi's but not finding any info out there on using pubmedR to search by doi. have looked into [entrez syntax](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3837/#_EntrezHelp_Entrez_Searching_Options_) but no luck there also. please help! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol figured it out [[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399144/extracting-affiliation-data-from-a-single-pubmed-record) was a **great** help] and wanted to post for anyone else who may have this same issue in the future. ended up using the easypubmed package instead tho

```
library(easyPubMed)

#loading list of DOIs
dois <- read.csv("dois.csv")

#convering dois to their associated PMID's 
pmids <- lapply(dois, get_pubmed_ids)

#using pmid's to extract abstract & article information as an xml thing
abstracts <- c()
for (i in c(1:length(pmids))){
  if (is.character(pmids[[i]][["IdList"]][["Id"]])==TRUE){
  abstracts[i] <- fetch_pubmed_data(pmids[[i]])
  }
}
abstracts <-as.list(abstracts) 

#making the xml thing readable by R
readAbstracts <- c()
for (i in c(1:length(abstracts))){
  if (is.na(abstracts[[i]]) == FALSE){
    readAbstracts[[i]] <- read_xml(abstracts[[i]]) 
  }
}

#now extracting desired information from the abstracts object
 <- data.frame()
for (i in c(1:length(pmids)){
  if (is.na(abstracts[[i]]) == FALSE && length(pmids[[i]]$IdList)<2){
    index <- i
    curRent <- readAbstracts[[i]] 
    pmid    <- xml2::xml_find_first( curRent, ".//PMID") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    title    <- xml2::xml_find_first( curRent, ".//ArticleTitle") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    authors <- paste( 
      xml2::xml_find_all( curRent, ".//AuthorList/Author/LastName") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      xml2::xml_find_all( curRent, ".//AuthorList/Author/ForeName") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      sep = ", " )
    affiliate <- xml2::xml_find_all( curRent, ".//AuthorList/Author/AffiliationInfo[1]/Affiliation") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    if(is.na(affiliate[1])==TRUE){
      affiliate <- NA
    }
    if(is.na(authors[1])==TRUE){
      authors <- NA
    }
    if(length(authors)>length(affiliate)){
      authors <- authors[c(1:length(affiliate))]
    }
    df <- data.frame( pmid = pmid, title=title, authors = authors, affiliate = affiliate, i = i)
    extractedInfo <-  rbind(extractedInfo, df)
    }
}
```

you may then use various methods to format 'extractedInfo' as you desire. cheers