# "facet not supported" bug on rcrossref

Tags: r

trying to extract author affiliations from dois as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268414/using-pubmedr-to-search-by-doi) -- now trying to use rcrossref instead of pubmedR

I have this code that always gives me this output:

```
> test <- cr_works(doi = '10.3390/ijms21165655', facet = TRUE)
Warning message:
400 (client error): /works/10.3390/ijms21165655 - This route does not support facet
```

Does this mean affiliation information is not available? Unsure what to do here. Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround using cr_cn adapted from the method [here](http://www.bioinformin.net/karel/post/papers/)

```
ref <- cr_cn(dois = '10.1590/S0104-12902020200348', format = "citeproc-json")
```

and then author affiliations are accessible using

```
affil <- ref[["author"]][["affiliation"]]
```